# Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.AppDelegate' to 'SwiftUI.AppDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I am currently experiencing a recurring crash in my SwiftUI application, and I am having trouble pinpointing the exact source of this issue.

The crash happens on the main thread and it seems to be related to a dynamic cast failure. However, I am not directly using any casting in the location pointed out by the stack trace.

There is a trend for the crash to happen mostly right after the app goes to background.

It seems to have started when I move to having the app use SwiftUI **AppDelegate** with **UIKit** `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`

Here is the stack trace related to the crash:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x7558 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7118 pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1d178 abort + 180
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b8ba8 swift::fatalError(unsigned int, char const*, ...) + 134
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3b8bc8 swift::warningv(unsigned int, char const*, char*) + 30
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3aeb90 swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, char const*) + 78
6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3aec0c swift::_conformsToProtocol(swift::OpaqueValue const*, swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptorRef<swift::InProcess>, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const**) + 122
7  libswiftCore.dylib             0x3afd24 swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditionalImpl(void const*, swift::TargetClassMetadata<swift::InProcess, swift::TargetAnyClassMetadataObjCInterop<swift::InProcess> > const*, char const*, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 366
8  SwiftUI                        0x233efc -[BaseDateProvider timeZone] + 964
9  SwiftUI                        0xb70c -[UITableViewCell(SwiftUI) swiftui_defaultRowHeight] + 568
10 SwiftUI                        0x116cd4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_1165 + 2496
11 UIKitCore                      0x174da8 +[UIScene _sceneForFBSScene:create:withSession:connectionOptions:] + 1036
12 UIKitCore                      0x209c48 -[UIApplication _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 884
13 UIKitCore                      0x209724 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 372
14 UIKitCore                      0x209544 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
15 FrontBoardServices             0x3220 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 344
16 FrontBoardServices             0x42fe0 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.80 + 120
17 FrontBoardServices             0x705c -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
18 FrontBoardServices             0x42c38 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 360
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x791c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
21 FrontBoardServices             0x11188 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
22 FrontBoardServices             0x10d24 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
23 FrontBoardServices             0x135d0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
24 CoreFoundation                 0xd3128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
25 CoreFoundation                 0xdf7b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
26 CoreFoundation                 0x645e8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
27 CoreFoundation                 0x7a0d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
28 CoreFoundation                 0x7f3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
29 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
30 UIKitCore                      0x39d6e8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
31 UIKitCore                      0x39d34c UIApplicationMain + 340
32 SwiftUI                        0x1bc41c OUTLINED_FUNCTION_895 + 2472
33 SwiftUI                        0x1229bc block_copy_helper.1 + 496
34 SwiftUI                        0x10ca64 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_901 + 2752
35 SleepTrackerApp                0xf014 main + 13 (SleepTrackerApp.swift:13)
36 ???                            0x1b72b6dec (Missing)
```

Here is the Declaration of the SwiftUI.App:

```
@main
struct SleepTrackerApp: SwiftUI.App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = PreSplashViewModel()
    @StateObject private var deepLinkHandler = SwiftUIDeepLinkHandler.shared
    @StateObject private var navigationController = NavigationController(rootView: AnyView(PreSplash()))
    
    init() {
        AppDelegate.shared = appDelegate
    }
```

And here is the AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    static internal var shared: AppDelegate!

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        let sceneConfiguration = UISceneConfiguration(name: "Scene Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
        sceneConfiguration.delegateClass = SwiftUISceneDelegate.self
        return sceneConfiguration
    }
    
    ...
```

And here is my SceneDelegate:

```
class SwiftUISceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    @LazyInjected(\.sleepRecorderManager)
    private var recorderManager
    
    func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        DeepLinkHandler.handle(url, internalDeepLink: true)
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let firstUrlContext = connectionOptions.userActivities.first, let url = firstUrlContext.webpageURL  {
            LoggerManager.shared.debug(url.absoluteString)
        }
    }
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
        guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else { return }
        
        SwiftUIDeepLinkHandler.shared.handleDeepLink(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include some code: the declaration that uses `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor`, and the declaration of your app delegate class.

Comment: @robmayoff Thanks! I added some insight as to when it happens as well

Comment: Can you upload a sample project to the github and share the link? so that we could reproduce the issue

Comment: @arturdev It's not a 100% bug, I was able to reproduce randomly, ~1% of my user are getting it, but it's still the most occurring crash and it's been there since I move to SwiftUI App lifecycle...

Comment: I also have a scene delegate in the AppDelegate, I added the definition of those class as well just now

Comment: One thing I read somewhere is that it could be some library that are swizzling, and internally casting the app. But I dont know how to catch which library is doing that

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the code that you have provided. But there is a catch when using **custom app delegate** in a **SwiftUI app lifecycle**.

Wherever you use app delegate make sure you use it by accessing the shared instance `AppDelegate.shared` or like this in **SwiftUI Views**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    var body: some View {
       ...
    }
}
```

do not access it via `UIApplication.shared.delegate` as it hosts other **internal SwiftUI app delegate**

```
(lldb) po UIApplication.shared.delegate
▿ Optional<UIApplicationDelegate>
  ▿ some : <SwiftUI.AppDelegate: 0x60000214a3a0>
```

Just make sure you (or the libraries you use) use the app delegate in a proper way.

Comment: when I do I search in my project including the Pods, there is no use of UIApplication.shared.delegate... Is there a way to pinpoint where that call is made?

Comment: You can put a `Symbolic Breakpoint` with `[UIApplication delegate]` symbol to get notified when the delegate property is read

Comment: I was only able to repro once or twice, so having a breakpoint would most probably not help me too...

Comment: This didn't fix my issue but I awarded you the points for the efforts ^^"

Comment: @Jaythaking Thanks a lot, but still I would like to help you) In the stack-trace I can see some Facebook related code, and considering this issue https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/2010 I think it might be it) What's your FB SDK version?